# XSLT: Replace only certain subnodes of an element in a template, apply-templates on the other

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I have to transform an XML into another XML, and I've currently a small issue:
In my XSLT I match an item and I replace some of its sub elements, and I would like the rest to be replaced by the `apply-template`.

Example:

With this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigurationNodes>
   <Versions>
      <PackagesA Version="1.8" />
      <PackageB Version="1.1" />
      <PackageC Version="1.7" />
   </Versions>
   <ConfigurationNode  Type="SomeSpecialType">
      <Name>MyName</Name>
      <Revision>0</Revision>
      <Description >The big full description here</Description>
      <Status Type="SpecialType2">
        <Value>Normal</Value>
        <Severity>255</Severity>
      </Status>
   </ConfigurationNode>
</ConfigurationNodes>
```

I would like to end with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigurationNodes>
   <Versions>
      <PackagesA Version="1.8" />
      <PackageB Version="1.1" />
      <PackageC Version="1.7" />
   </Versions>
   <Object Name="Configuration" NodeType="SomeOtherType">
      <Property Name="Name" Value="MyName" Type="System.String" />
      <Property Name="Description" Value="The big full description here" Type="System.String" />
      <Property Name="Revision" Value="0" Type="System.Int32" />
      <Object Name="Status" Type="SomeOtherSpecialType2">
         <Property Name="Value" Value="Normal" Type="System.String" />
         <Property Name="Severity" Value="255" Type="System.Int32" />
      </Object>
   </Object>
</ConfigurationNodes>
```

Currently I've this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="*[@Type='SomeSpecialType']">
    <Object Name="Configuration" NodeType="SomeOtherType">
      <Property Name="Name" Value="{Name/text()}" Type="System.String"/>
      <Property Name="Description" Value="{Description/text()}" Type="System.String"/>
      <Property Name="Revision" Value="{Revision/text()}" Type="System.Int32" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Status"/>
    </Object>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@Type='SpecialType2']">
    <Object Name="Status" Type="SomeOtherSpecialType2">
      <Property Name="Value" Value="Normal" Type="System.String"  />
      <Property Name="Severity" Value="255" Type="System.Int32"  />
    </Object>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which returns me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigurationNodes>
   <Versions>
      <PackagesA Version="1.8" />
      <PackageB Version="1.1" />
      <PackageC Version="1.7" />
   </Versions>
   <Object Name="Configuration" NodeType="SomeOtherType">
   <Property Name="Name" Value="MyName" Type="System.String" />
   <Property Name="Description" Value="The big full description here" Type="System.String" />
   <Property Name="Revision" Value="0" Type="System.Int32" />
   <Name>MyName</Name>
   <Revision>0</Revision>
   <Description>The big full description here</Description>
   <Object Name="Status" Type="SomeOtherSpecialType2">
      <Property Name="Value" Value="Normal" Type="System.String" />
      <Property Name="Severity" Value="255" Type="System.Int32" /></Object>
   </Object>
</ConfigurationNodes>
```

So the element used in the first template are still copied(because they are not matched I guess).

I also know that I could put `<xsl:apply-templates select="Status"/>`, which will give me the expected result, but in my future real case, I would like that all unmatched sub elements check the other template based on their type.

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your first template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@Type='SomeSpecialType']">
    <Object Name="Configuration" NodeType="SomeOtherType">
        <Property Name="Name" Value="{Name}" Type="System.String"/>
        <Property Name="Description" Value="{Description}" Type="System.String"/>
        <Property Name="Revision" Value="{Revision}" Type="System.Int32" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Name or self::Description or self::Revision)]"/>
    </Object>
</xsl:template>
```

This will apply templates to all children of the current element except those you have already used explicitly to populate the properties.

---

### Edit:

> I was more looking to a way where I don't have to specify all the
>   elements

Then I'd suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@Type='SomeSpecialType']">
    <Object Name="Configuration" NodeType="SomeOtherType">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Object>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@Type='SpecialType2']">
    <Object Name="Status" Type="SomeOtherSpecialType2">
        <Property Name="Value" Value="Normal" Type="System.String"  />
        <Property Name="Severity" Value="255" Type="System.Int32"  />
    </Object>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name | Description">
    <Property Name="{name()}" Value="{.}" Type="System.String"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Revision">
    <Property Name="Revision" Value="{.}" Type="System.Int32"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was more looking to a way where I don't have to specify all the elements(in my case, could be 30+ elements at several places)

Comment: Well I see your point, but in my case, the Name/... are used in very different context, only the parent can now if we should contain it. But thank you, I guess your first proposal is the best I can do